# How to speed up joomla slow mysql queries? 

Tags: mysql, joomla

i installed an joomla website on an vps with nginx+php-fpm, mysql....with low traffic

everything load pretty fast; except the generated joomla page because of slow mysql querys. is there a way to cache/speed them up?

mysql query  does not work because there is a low traffic(maybe an user/one hour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a lot of sites with Joomla (although admittedly not paired with nginx) and never had to even consider this. How much content does your installation have? It would have to be an awful lot before any serious thought needed to be given to database tuning.

Are you sure the database engine is the cause of the problem? You can verify this by turning on the debug output in Joomla's global configuration (under 'System'), which will show the queries and some timing info in the footer. Don't forget to turn it off when you're done with it!

Have a look at the timing for the `Application afterRender` entry. Unless you're consistently seeing multi-second values there, I'd be looking elsewhere for your problem.

Comment: I'd have to agree. I've built many dozens of Joomla sites, and administrate several hundred at the moment. Slow database queries isn't something Joomla tends to suffer from.

Comment: my problem is that it is just an corporate website and it still takes about 0.7seconds to generate, which i consider a lot

nginx or apache does not matter that much in this case

Comment: I tend to agree with @KingJackaL, that doesn't sound like a problem worth obsessing over. However, you could try turning off all but the essential modules and components and see if it makes any difference. Sounds like busywork though.

Comment: my bad, the page was loading slow because of some useless javascript. .....i care because it`s my first project with joomla and if i could not make the site load fast for such a simple project i could not use it in the future

Comment: I'd be careful with that reasoning. Just because something doesn't run super-fast in a minimal use-case doesn't mean it's not useable. Scalability isn't always linear...